# Kann man mit "eigen" ausdrücken, dass X *nur* bei Y vorkommt?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice

Wenn von B, S und D *nur* B eine eine bestimmte Eigenschaft aufweist, gibt es eine Möglichkeit, dies mit dem Wort "eigen" zu vermitteln?

Beispiel:

> Das dem Deutschen eigene Eszett.
>   Dieses Feature ist Python (zu?) eigen.

Gibt es sonst ein Adjektiv, mit dem das möglich ist?

Comment: Im Duden kommt diese Verwendung von "zu eigen" nicht, daher im Beispiel nur geklammert vor.

Comment: Das ist ziemlich gehoben und auch nicht unmißverständlich; normalerweise würde man sagen, _X ist eine Besonderheit des Deutschen_. Natürlich ist das kein Adjektiv.

Comment: @chirlu Man könnte die Frage vll. zu "Gibt es eine Möglichkeit, [den genannten Aspekt] ohne Nebensatz, Infinitiv- bzw. Partizipialgruppe auszudrücken?" umformulieren.

Comment: Obwohl „eigen“ bedeuten kann „auffällig abweichend von anderen“, lässt es anscheinend genügend Spielraum, um nicht „ausschließlich-exklusives Alleinstellungsmerkmal“ auszudrücken.

Comment: Das angestellte 'zu eigen' finde ich super. So drückt sich halt kein Trottel aus. Alternativ: Bindestrich exklusiv. Holprig aber knackig.
(Ich kann leider keine Kommentare abgegeben )

Comment: evtl. _spezifisch, charakteristisch, einzigartig, herausragend, *unik ← unique_ und _Alleinstellungsmerkmal → ?alleinstellend_

Comment: "X ist **ausschliesslich** der Fall bei Y", etwas in der Art würde ich vorschlagen

Comment: In case the appearance of the term _eigen_ is more important than the word class, there is also the option to nominalize: _Eine Eigenheit von X (im Vergleich zu A, B) ist Y_. ( _Y is a peculiarity of X (with respect to A, B_) ).

Answer (score 4):

> X ist ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal von Y

Ich würde mit den Kommentaren übereinstimmen, dass "X ist Y eigen" durchaus in die richtige Richtung geht, und ich persönlich finde es gar nicht so unnatürlich, aber es ist eher im Sinne von "ein Charakteristikum", nicht "ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal" zu verstehen. Daher der Vorschlag.

Kein Adjektiv, aber "the closest you'll get", wie es im Englischen so schön heißt.

Comment: Die Formulierung ist (ohne "zu") durchaus gebraeuchlich. Sehr gerne in der Form "Mit der ihm eigenen Gelassenheit...". Sie beschreibt dann Eigenschaften die fuer jemanden typisch sind. Wie sehr das Merkmal ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal sein muss, oder lediglich typisch, darauf wage ich mich noch nicht festzulegen.

Comment: Genau das habe ich doch, mit Bezug auf obige Kommentare zur Frage, auch gesagt?!

Comment: Ja, beinahe. Darum habe ich es ja auch als Kommentar geposted.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wörtchen *eigen* ist ein Eigenschaftswort (Adjektiv), welches die Zugehörigkeit, die *Eigentümlichkeit* oder auch *Eigenschaft* beschreibt. ([S. Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eigen).) Das Adjektiv *eigentümlich* ist oft Synonym für *eigen*. Es gehört schon sehr lange zur deutschen Sprache, was sich auch darin ausdrückt, dass es in anderen Sprachen oft vom lateinischen *proprius* (beständig, unvergänglich; wesentlich, eigentlich; eigen, eigentümlich; persönlich, individuell) abgeleitete Übersetzungen hat. Es hat auch noch andere Bedeutungen als die gefragte (s. u., [Synonyme](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/eigen.php)).

> La lettre ß est un caractère propre à l'écriture allemande.
>
> Der Buchstabe ß ist ein der deutschen Schrift eigenes Schriftzeichen.

Vermutlich ist die Verbindung *proprius*-*eigen* im Mittelalter entstanden, obwohl die Wurzel von *eigen* sich schon früher ins Englische verzweigt hat (*own*, [s. wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eigen).), aber dann auch Konkurrenz aus dem lateinischen bekam (*property*, Eigentum), und diese auch im Sinne "Eigenschaft" wie *eigen* ([*proper to*](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/proper+to+sth.html)) benutzt werden kann.

Eine besondere Eigenschaft von *eigen* ist, dass es nicht gesteigert werden kann, also ein [Absolutadjektiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolutadjektiv) ist! (Es kann nichts „eigener“ als eigen sein.)

Die Worte *eigentümlich* (mit [heute] anderer Bedeutung als *Eigentum*), *eigenartig*, *eigentlich*, *Eigenheit*, *Eigner*, (*sich*) *eignen* sowie das substantivierte *Eigen* (gleich *Eigentum*) teilen ihre Etymologie mit *eigen* (bzw. dem vermutlich ursprünglichen, proto-germanischen Ausdruck).

Und um die ursprüngliche Frage nach "sonst einem Adjektiv" (also [Synonymen](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/eigen.php)) zu beantworten: *zugehörig*, *kennzeichnend* oder *charakteristisch* scheinen mir für die gefragte Bedeutung passende Kandidaten zu sein.

Comment: Danke für die tolle Antwort!

Comment: Danke. Es darf übrigens jeder die Antwort editieren, und zum Verbessern allemal. Das gibt dann auch Kudos. Und der Fragesteller darf auch die Antwort "akzeptieren", die ihm am besten gefällt. Das gibt dann auch Kudos, aber für den anderen! :-)

Comment: @Dirk Almost. Als "Accepter" bekommt man auch 2 Pünktchen, und für's Editieren bekommen nur diejenigen was ab, die noch nicht soviel Rep haben ;)

Comment: Mannomann. Ganz schön kompliziert. (Und etwas merkwürdig ist es schon, dass dieser Kommentar jetzt belohnt wird.)

Answer (score 1):

Im Sinne der Beispiele wäre *gebräuchlich* oder *vorkommend* noch eine Alternative. Also „Das im Deutschen gebräuchliche Eszett.“

Das drückt allerdings keine Exklusivität aus. Dazu müsste man es dann weiter umschreiben: „Das nur im Deutschen gebräuchliche Eszett.“